# Read a JSON Serialized List<string>

Tags: c#, json, jquery

I have an ordinary `List<string>` that I convert to JSON with `System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

The result is something similar to this

```
[
  "string1",
  "string2",
  "string3",
  "string4",
  "string5",
  "string6"
]
```

Now how do I read this in jQuery? I prefer to be able to loop them out one by one.
Or am I supposed to make a better JSON object and return that, if so are there any good ways to make a JSON object from a `List<string>`?

Comment: How are you getting that data into javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AJAX request in order to get the `List` to the client and the assign it to a JavaScript `Array` object:

```
var list = new Array();
$.ajax({
     url: myUrl,
     success: function(data){
         list = data;
     }
});
```

You can next iterate the `list` in order to access each element, either with jQuery (`$.each`), or with regular JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   //do whatever with *list[i]*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it by looping it using **`$.each`**

```
$.each(yourList, function (index, value) {
    console.log(index, value);
});
```